# How to create a face out of edges

Tags: edges, faces

Is there any way to create a face out of these selected and enclosed edges in the screenshot? I have tried using the F key but the face overlapped part of the model. Any help is appreciated. :D

[image]

Comment: try Ctrl+F--> Grid_fill ( the settings are down in the tools panel )

Comment: This guy invented Cybertruck! 

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You definitely need more then one face to fill that side, I used six.

The best way to fill that shape would be to look at your model, and think about what edges you need where, then decide what faces should go where. You should be thinking about edge flow, and face loops for your entire model.

In this gif I added two edges on the bottom, then by selecting two edges at a time pressing <kbd>F</kbd>, filled the side with new faces. 
[image: animated gif]

Comment: If you have an even number of vertices, use Grid Fill.