# Creating a plane based on nodes

Tags: modeling, objects

I have just started working with Blender and have run into a problem:
I'd like to add a plane to a side of an object, but I don't know how to do it since it has curved edges, is there any way to add a plane based on the nodes I have selected, or do I have to do something else?
Grateful for any help!
[image: Want to create a plane that covers the bottom of the object]

Comment: Welcome to [bse](https://blender.stackexchange.com)  Would use the terminology _vertices (vertex for singular)_ rather than _nodes_.  If you want to fill the verts with a face press F.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34525/how-to-create-a-face-out-of-edges and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/92586/is-there-any-way-to-fill-the-whole-back-of-this-mesh/ or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75258/how-to-fill-the-surface-of-a-wireframe-sphere-in-blender and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64121/how-can-i-create-a-face-with-a-rounded-edge

Answer (score 4):

As Batfinger already said the points on the mesh are called **Vertices** and not **Nodes**. Nodes are a completely different sphere of blender which includes stuff like materials and compositing.

As for you question, selecting the **Vertices** and pressing <kbd>F</kbd> will fill in the faces.

Comment: Thank you! Did not notice that you've commented and figured it out on my own, but the but I appriciate the gesture.